# So I made list of words in text document and it's updating after button is pressed. Words are displayed randomly

Tags: python, random, kivy

So this code is made with `python` and `kivy`. Problem is that sometimes words may appear more than once. Basically, it's repeating some words. The goal is that I don't want to repeat a single specific word more than once. Here's my `python` code:

```
file = open("words.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
file = file.read()

individual_words = file.split()
random_number = randint(0, len(individual_words))
self.ids.words_areva.text = str(individual_words[random_number])
```

Comment: `set(['hi', 'hi', 'hello'])`

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for. sorry

Comment: What do you mean: `it's repeating some words`? You only pick *one* word from your file.

Comment: Yeap. it's repeating some words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to a set:

```py
file = open("words.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
file = file.read()

individual_words = list(set(file.split()))
random_number = randint(0, len(individual_words))
self.ids.words_areva.text = str(individual_words[random_number])
```

Comment: 'set' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Sorry, fixed. Now converts back to a list.

Comment: Thank you so much! Simple and effective❤

Comment: Glad I could help! Please upvote the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add every word you get to a list, and check every time if random word is in that list.

```
file = open("words.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
file = file.read()

listOfWordsDone = []
individual_words = file.split()

while True:
    random_number = randint(0, len(individual_words))
    if (individual_words[random_number] not in listOfWordsDone):
        self.ids.words_areva.text = str(individual_words[random_number])
        listOfWordsDone.append(individual_words[random_number])
        break
```

Comment: Your code worked too but I accepted other ones answer because it was simple. Thanks anyway!❤❤

Comment: This is fairly computationally expensive. The worst case scenario is O(inf)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correctly, you have a file with all the random words and the button just adding random words to the file,
so why don't you check if the random word already exists in the file?

```
random_word = 'abc'
while random_word in individual_words:
     random_word = 'other random word..'
```